# How to order a pre-ordered table

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-sql

When i query the database with this "union select":

```
select stampata_sn,numero_conto,dest_stampa,portata,categoria,prog_inser,nodo,desc_art,prezzo_un,quantita from comanda where contiene_variante='1' and ntav_comanda='1' and posizione='CONTO' and stato_record='ATTIVO'   and numero_conto = '1' 
union all
select stampata_sn,numero_conto,dest_stampa,portata,categoria,prog_inser,nodo,desc_art,prezzo_un,sum(quantita) as quantita from comanda where (contiene_variante !='1' or contiene_variante is null) and length(nodo)=3 and ntav_comanda='1' and posizione='CONTO' and stato_record='ATTIVO'  and numero_conto = '1'  group by desc_art 
union all
select stampata_sn,numero_conto,dest_stampa,portata,categoria,prog_inser,nodo,desc_art,prezzo_un,quantita from comanda where length(nodo)=7 and ntav_comanda='1'  and posizione='CONTO' and stato_record='ATTIVO'  and numero_conto = '1'  order by nodo asc;
```

I extract this datas, in that order:

```
PROGRESSIVO NODO    PRODOTTO            QUANTITA
0           000     SAN PELLEGRINO      1
1           001     MINERALWASSER 0.2 l 1
2           002     MINERALWASSER 0.4 l 1
3           003     COCA COLA 0.2 l     3
4           004     COCA COLA 0.4 l     1
5           005     COLA LIGHT 0.2 l    5
6           006     COLA LIGHT 0.4 l    3
7           007     APFELSAFT 0.4 l     1
12          007     012 +SCHWARZWALD    1
13          007     013 -ERDBEEREN      1
8           008     APFELSAFT 0.2 l     2
10          010     SPRITE 0.4 l        1
11          011     SPRITE 0.2 l        1
```

The order is correct because the variants are linked to the products, but I want to see them in alphabetical order, like this:

```
PROGRESSIVO NODO        PRODOTTO            QUANTITA
11          008         APFELSAFT 0.2 I     2
7           007         APFELSAFT 0.4 I     1
8           007 012     + SCHWARZWALD       1
10          007 013     - ERDBEEREN         1
3           003         COCA COCA 0.2 I     3
4           004         COCA COLA 0.4 I     1
5           005         COLA LIGHT 0.2 l    5
6           006         COLA LIGHT 0.4 l    3
1           001         MINERALWASSER 0.2 l 1
2           002         MINERALWASSER 0.4 l 1
0           000         SAN PELLEGRINO      1
12          011         SPRITE 0.2 l        1
13          010         SPRITE 0.4 l        1
```

How could I do?

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: I got the first results I showed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and wrap your SQL in an outer SQL like below

```
select A.stampata_sn
      ,A.numero_conto
      ,A.dest_stampa
      ,A.portata
      ,A.categoria
      ,A.prog_inser
      ,A.nodo
      ,A.desc_art
      ,A.prezzo_un
      ,A.quantita
  FROM 
(
select stampata_sn
      ,numero_conto
      ,dest_stampa
      ,portata
      ,categoria
      ,prog_inser
      ,nodo
      ,desc_art
      ,prezzo_un
      ,quantita 
  from comanda 
 where contiene_variante='1' 
   and ntav_comanda='1' 
   and posizione='CONTO' 
   and stato_record='ATTIVO'   
   and numero_conto = '1' 
union all
select stampata_sn
      ,numero_conto
      ,dest_stampa
      ,portata
      ,categoria
      ,prog_inser
      ,nodo
      ,desc_art
      ,prezzo_un
      ,sum(quantita) as quantita 
  from comanda 
 where (contiene_variante !='1' or contiene_variante is null) 
   and length(nodo)=3 
   and ntav_comanda='1' 
   and posizione='CONTO' 
   and stato_record='ATTIVO'  
   and numero_conto = '1'  group by desc_art 
union all
select stampata_sn
      ,numero_conto
      ,dest_stampa
      ,portata
      ,categoria
      ,prog_inser
      ,nodo
      ,desc_art
      ,prezzo_un
      ,quantita 
  from comanda 
 where length(nodo)=7 
   and ntav_comanda='1'  
   and posizione='CONTO' 
   and stato_record='ATTIVO'  
   and numero_conto = '1'  
) A
order by <Field to order by here> asc;
```

I am unsure what the field you would want to use to order by since the column header PRODOTTO does not show up in the column list. You could use any of the column names to order by example - "A.portata".

Also your 2nd SQL that groups by desc_art does not seem ANSI-compliant, typically when you group by all the non-aggregate columns in the selected column list should be part of your group by. You may want to review this and check that you are getting proper results.

Answer (score 0):

I need to get the main product with its variants, then regroup the other products, and sum their quantities.

Then I want to order them alphabetically.

Example.

If I have this:

```
1 Spaghetti

1 Spaghetti
+ pomodoro
+cipolle 

5 Caffè

6 Coca cola
```

It's wrong.

I need to get:

```
5 Caffè
6 Coca cola
```

then the Spaghetti with its variants, split from the other products with the same name (this function is already working):

```
1 Spaghetti

1 Spaghetti
+pomodoro
+cipolle
```